# How can I get a user ranking sorted by question reputation?

Tags: support, data-explorer

On every stackexchange site you can rank the top (all time) users by total reputation.

Is it also possible to rank the top users only taking into account the reputation earned by questions (and not by answers)? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only see it per tag, in the Top Users page of the tag, e.g. [C# Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) on Stack Overflow:

> [image]

This shows the total reputation earned from questions of this tag.

To see total reputation from questions with all tags, you'll have to use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and calculate the reputation manually based on votes, however the query will be complicated to write for two main reasons:

- Community Wiki - you'll have to check if a question is marked, or was marked, as Community Wiki at some point, and ignore upvotes/downvotes cast in those periods of time.
- Daily reputation cap - you'll have to ignore reputation from upvotes if it pass the 200 rep cap.

To get a rough idea, here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/439432/user-ranking-for-questions-only-simple-no-check-for-cw-or-rep-cap) to get the user ranking, without checking those two restrictions: (i.e. calculate raw reputation based on upvotes and downvotes only)

```sql
Select Top 100 p.OwnerUserId As [User Link], 
    Count(Distinct p.Id) As [Total Questions], 
    Sum(
        Case 
            When votetypeid = 2 Then 5  -- up vote
            When votetypeid = 3 Then -2 -- down vote
        End 
     ) As [Total Reputation]
From Posts p Inner Join Votes v On v.PostId=p.Id And v.VoteTypeId In (2,3) --upvotes, downvotes
Where p.OwnerUserId Is Not Null And p.OwnerUserId > 0 And p.PostTypeId=1 --Questions
Group By p.OwnerUserId
Order By [Total Reputation] Desc
```

It is limited to top 100 to prevent timeout, and as you can easily see, gives much more reputation, for the users with highly upvotes questions.

Comment: How would the query look like if one ignores the two problems mentioned above?

Comment: Quite simple, will add it soon to the answer.

Comment: @student done..

Comment: But that doesn't take down votes into account? This does, including accepts: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/439432/user-ranking-for-questions-only-simple-no-check-for-cw-or-rep-cap

Comment: @rene true, totally slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: Down votes slipped your mind? Are they that uncommon? ;)